# Transaction reverts when using custom router contract while swapping tokens to ETH on Uniswap

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I am in the process of setting up my own smart contract on the Ethereum network for executing transactions through Uniswap v2. I've come across an issue where all transactions get reverted when the safeTransferETH function is executed by swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens.
Screenshot from tenderly:
[image: Image1]

My router:

```
/**
 * @dev Internal function to calculate fee based on the amount and whitelist status.
 * @param amount Amount for which the fee needs to be calculated.
 * @return Fee amount.
 */
function _calculateFee(uint256 amount) private view returns (uint256) {
    return isWhitelisted[msg.sender] ? 0 : (amount * feeBasisPoints) / 10000;
}


/**
 * @notice Checks the allowance of a token to a spender and approves it if needed.
 * @dev This is a helper function to ensure a spender can pull a specific amount of tokens.
 * @param token The address of the ERC20 token.
 * @param spender The address of the entity which will spend the tokens.
 * @param amount The amount of tokens to be approved.
 */
function _checkAndApprove(address token, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
    if (IERC20(token).allowance(address(this), spender) < amount) {
        IERC20(token).approve(spender, amount);
    }
}

/**
 * @notice Swaps tokens that might have a transfer fee for a minimum amount of ETH.
 * @dev This function is similar to swapTokensForETHV2, but optimized for tokens that take a fee on transfer.
 * @param amountIn The amount of tokens to be swapped.
 * @param amountOutMin The minimum amount of ETH expected in return.
 * @param path Array of token addresses used for the swap, where path[0] is the input token and the last address is WETH.
 * @param to Address that will receive the ETH.
 * @param deadline Time by which the swap should complete, or it will revert.
 */
function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint256 deadline) external payable{
    require(path.length > 1, "Path should be at least 2 tokens long");
    require(to != address(0), "Invalid recipient address");
    require(amountIn > 0, "Amount in should be more than 0");

    uint256 feeAmount = _calculateFee(amountIn);
    IERC20(path[0]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    if (feeAmount > 0) IERC20(path[0]).transfer(feeWallet, feeAmount);
    
    _checkAndApprove(path[0], uniswapV2RouterAddress, amountIn - feeAmount);

    IUniswapV2Router02(uniswapV2RouterAddress).swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        amountIn - feeAmount,
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        to,
        deadline
    );
    emit Swapped(msg.sender, amountIn, amountOutMin);
}
```

I am executing transactions using python code:

```
    def sell(self):
    # Get details from the user
    token_address = self.w3.to_checksum_address(input("Please provide token address for selling: "))
    tokens_amount = float(input("Enter the amount of tokens you want to sell: "))
    min_eth_expected = float(input("Enter the minimum amount of Ether you expect in return: "))

    self.approve_tokens(token_address, tokens_amount)
    erc20_contract = self.w3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=read_token_abi())
    balance = erc20_contract.functions.balanceOf(self.w3.to_checksum_address(self.config.WALLET_ADDRESS)).call()

    tokens_amount_wei = int(tokens_amount * 10**18) # Convert token amount to its smallest unit
    min_eth_expected_wei = self.w3.to_wei(min_eth_expected, 'ether')  # Convert expected Ether to wei
    deadline = self.w3.eth.get_block("latest")["timestamp"] + 1500
    # Build the transaction data
    transaction_data = self.contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        balance,
        min_eth_expected_wei,
        [self.w3.to_checksum_address(token_address), self.w3.to_checksum_address(self.config.WETH_ADDRESS)],
        self.w3.to_checksum_address(self.config.CONTRACT_ADDRESS),
        deadline
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': self.w3.to_checksum_address(self.config.WALLET_ADDRESS),
        'gas': 2000000,
        'gasPrice': self.w3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': self.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.config.WALLET_ADDRESS)
    })

    signed_transaction = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction_data, self.config.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY)
    tx_hash = self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
    print()

    # Wait for transaction receipt and verify
    receipt = self.w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    if receipt.status == 1:
        print("Token sale transaction completed successfully.")
    else:
        print("Token sale transaction completed unsuccessfully.")
    print()
    print("--------------------------------")
    print(tx_hash.hex())
    print("--------------------------------")
```

Transaction are working fine when I use "write contract" in etherscan: [URL](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x6369323a413e45796902e830026cbb1d980c75365d15c02533240a5cb1295b51)

But it is getting reverted when I try to use my own router: [URL](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x220a0738734994de899bc9a29f72446bac73f698d780f46d14f31427ad25d9c0)

Does anyone faced the same issue?